# How can I catch this Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode error?

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to automate some interaction with a web app, but capybara keeps throwing this

`` {"id":"c0616941-0375-4c42-a6d8-a3a5201c5235","name":"tag_name","args":[3,1]}
{"command_id":"c0616941-0375-4c42-a6d8-a3a5201c5235","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.ObsoleteNode","args":[]}}
Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode: Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.14.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:21:in `rescue in command'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.14.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:17:in `command'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.14.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:111:in `tag_name'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:258:in `block in tag_name'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:258:in `tag_name'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:374:in `inspect'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>' ``

I'd like to catch this exception and throw it away, but when I try

`begin
  @session.first(:button, 'Save').click
rescue Capybara::Poltergeist::ObsoleteNode
  puts "Whoops!"
end`

It still throws the exception and doesn't print out "Whoops!".

Comment: I highly doubt you're getting an ObsoleteNode error from the line you have the rescue around. Check to make sure the line raising the error is the one you think it is.  Your stack trace actually shows it coming from irb trying to print out the element.

Comment: If you just want to be able to run that command in irb - then you can do `@session.first(:button, 'Save').click && true` so the result of the command is true (instead of the button element) and irb won't try to inspect the button element (which has already gone away)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much.